# TensorFlow is not using GPU

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, gpu

I sat up an AWS Deep Learning machine using the AMI. Now I'm trying to run the simple starter example from the TensorFlow

```
# Creates a graph.
a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b')
c = tf.matmul(a, b)
# Creates a session with log_device_placement set to True.
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
# Runs the op.
print(sess.run(c))
```

But it appears that my machine is not using my GPUs.

> MatMul_2: (MatMul): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0 2017-07-09
>   00:51:03.830238: I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/simple_placer.cc:847] MatMul_2:
>   (MatMul)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0 MatMul_1: (MatMul):
>   /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0 2017-07-09 00:51:03.830259: I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/simple_placer.cc:847] MatMul_1:
>   (MatMul)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0 MatMul: (MatMul):
>   /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0 2017-07-09 00:51:03.830271: I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/simple_placer.cc:847] MatMul:
>   (MatMul)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0 b_2: (Const):
>   /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0 2017-07-09 00:51:03.830283: I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/simple_placer.cc:847] b_2:
>   (Const)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0 a_2: (Const):
>   /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0 2017-07-09 00:51:03.830312: I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/simple_placer.cc:847] a_2:
>   (Const)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0 b_1: (Const):
>   /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0 2017-07-09 00:51:03.830324: I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/simple_placer.cc:847] b_1:
>   (Const)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0 a_1: (Const):
>   /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0 2017-07-09 00:51:03.830337: I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/simple_placer.cc:847] a_1:
>   (Const)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0 b: (Const):
>   /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0 2017-07-09 00:51:03.830348: I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/simple_placer.cc:847] b:
>   (Const)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0 a: (Const):
>   /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0 2017-07-09 00:51:03.830358: I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/simple_placer.cc:847] a:
>   (Const)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0

If I try to manually specify GPU with with `tf.device('/gpu:0'):` I get the following error:

> InvalidArgumentError: Cannot assign a device for operation 'MatMul_3':
>   Operation was explicitly assigned to /device:GPU:0 but available
>   devices are [ /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0 ]. Make sure the
>   device specification refers to a valid device.     [[Node: MatMul_3 =
>   MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false,
>   _device="/device:GPU:0"](a_3, b_3)]]

The only change I made to the AMI was that I updated TensorFlow to the latest version

Here's what I see when I run *watch nvidia-smi*

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 367.57                 Driver Version: 367.57                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla K80           On   | 0000:00:1E.0     Off |                    0 |
| N/A   44C    P8    27W / 149W |      0MiB / 11439MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Have you tried this? https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/403

Comment: Can you provide more info? Which AMI are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I decided to relaunch with the latest available AMI from amazon (https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B01M0AXXQB) and it works. Not sure what went wrong before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.check your instance,do you select GPU?
use "watch nvidia-smi" to see GPU info.

2.check your AMI,and tensorflow version, maybe it doesn't support GPU or have some wrong config.

I use this AMI: Deep Learning AMI Amazon Linux (ami-296e7850).

Comment: Thanks, I added an edit to my post on the output of running watch nvidia-smi. I used the same version as you: https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B06VSPXKDX but for Ubuntu. After that I updated to TensorFlow 1.2